# Avoid repetition when mixing/painting textures

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I can't find a proper answer to my question and I'm not a pro in redering 3d images, but still have a bit of knwoledge, so I thought I 'd turn to the common knowledge to find a solution to my problem and help me.
I am trying to mix two textures and use a painted mask to factor this combination.
the result i am going for is: Having a concrete door frame in a stone wall, the trick is that the concrete is supposed to fill in the joints in between the stone cracks. That s the reason why i am painting it.
I manage to obtain what I want, except that my texture paint repeats itself (sees the red painted mask attached) instead of being just around the door frame. I know I'm missing something obvious here but I can't find what. Any help would be greatly apreciated.
Thank you very much in advance,

regards,

BD
[image: repetition of the painted mask]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since you have set "Repeat" in Image Texture node ...

Comment: It is set to repeat because the two other options won't work properly either.
Extend streches the concrete (red) part on the side wall, and clip won't allow me to partially have conrete on both sides of the corner.

Comment: Search for Unwrapp methods and UV mapping techniques ...

Comment: Thank you for the direction but I can't make it work. I set up the seems the way I need them (I want the concrete to flow on both sides of the corner wall) but somehow everything I have trides so far won't work.
Also: now the material appears purple as if it was missing, but renders properly and is not really missing, as I tried to relink it several time. So it makes it complicated to paint what I need.

Comment: Hey, I reduced my file size a lot, so I could up^load it but can't go lower than 48 Mo so I can't upload it on the platform. 
I uploaded it on this link though:
https://we.tl/t-ogYmgOCYh2
I hope this can help, thank you!

Comment: I created an answer, but I would like to encourage you to take a time to follow some beginner tutorials about unwrapping techniques  ... so you can get familiar how this all works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is many variants how to solve it ...

Most common (or practical) is make seams in a way of paper-cut ... in this way you can paint on texture in *3Dview* and *Image Editor* as well (because most of the edges are shared).

[image]

[image]

(I simplified your topology, just to make it more clear.)

[image]

If you need to paint in 3Dview only ... you don't need seams at all ... just press <kbd>U</kbd> *Unwrapp* > **Lightmap Pack** or **Smart UV Project** type to generate not overlapping UVmap. Than assign Image texture and paint.

With your current UVmap you can only assign specific material to each side individually.

[image]

Or you have to manually move each part of your UVmap (in UV editor) a side to place them without overlaps first.

Sidenote: if it is not a necessary, place your object to a center (or close to center) of your Scene (World Origin). Current position 3 km from center generates glitches in viewport ("known" issue).